# Evolutionary algorithm in stochastic environment

Tags: optimization, heuristics, evolutionary-computing

Consider the following model problem:

I want to use an **evolutionary algorithm** to optimize the starting point of particles for which it is apriori clear where they would start in state space, but not **when**. Once a particle is placed, it is part of the dynamics, which is **stochastic**, i.e. whether certain particles interact is modeled by a random variable. A *mutation* of the evolutionary algorithm corresponds to slightly changing the time when the particle is introduced in the system.

I have now two choices:

1) I let the stochastic dynamics evolve *while* the evolutionary algorithm is optimizing, i.e. after every mutation I *draw* a new interaction environment from the distribution. That means, the algorithm is evaluating every situation with a different environment (drawn from one fixed distribution).

2) I draw an interaction pattern for every particle *apriori* to have one fixed environment (we assume they can be drawn independently). Then I let the algorithm optimize my problem in that deterministic environment. I do that for *several* environments and take some statistic over the solution.

Does someone have experience with those two approaches and can tell me their advantages and disadvantages from a practical point of view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with option 1.

A dynamic training environment is a good way to produce a robust solution (after all natural evolution, which is the inspiration for EA, is always dynamic).

Moreover *"take some statistics over the solutions"* can be a very hard problem (you shouldn't take for granted that there is a meaningful way to combine / extract information from multiple solutions).

Indeed there are some important aspects to consider:

- **population diversity have to be carefully monitored**. Often EAs are designed for a static optimization problem and the quick loss of diversity can be a problem in a dynamic environment;
- it seems that you have a system in which environmental change occurs rapidly. **Try to slow down the environment**: do not draw a new interaction environment after every mutation but wait for a sequence of mutations (in Genetic Programming this is the approach taken in [Dynamic Training Subset Selection](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.55.1161){1}). I'm not sure this will work, but it's worth a try;
- **supply the EA with an explicit memory** (sometimes called *Valhalla*) so that the EA can recall useful information from past generations (e.g {5}).

---

This is small compendium of interesting papers.

Looking for further resources, consider that there are many kinds of dynamic environments: e.g. noisy fitness functions, environments with optimum changing over time... they are somewhat different problems but share many interesting techniques.

Also it seems to me that you're describing a so called *co-adaptive environment* (each individual's evolution drives other individuals evolution and individuals change their fitness landscape evermore). You may find interesting techniques in papers about *co-evolution*.

1. [Dynamic Training Subset Selection for Supervised Learning in Genetic Programming](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.55.1161) by Chris Gathercole, Peter Ross (1994).
2. [Genetic Algorithm for Adaptation to Dynamic Environments - A survey](https://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~dwcorne/RSR/ga-adapt.pdf) by Naoki Mori, Hajime Kita (2000).
3. [Evolutionary Dynamic Optimization - A survey of the state of the art](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2012/05/3480.pdf) by Juergen Branke, Trung Thanh Nguyen, Shengxiang Yang (2012).
4. [An evolutionary approach for time dependant optimization](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/citations;jsessionid=CBCDCD09087DB47A6DFA1EFA6B09397D?doi=10.1.1.26.3552) by Philippe Collard, Cathy Escazut, Alessio Gaspar (1997).
5. "Memory enhanced evolutionary algorithms for changing optimization problems" by Juergen Branke (1999).
6. [Evolutionary Algorithms and Dynamic Optimization Problems](http://www.imn.htwk-leipzig.de/~weicker/publications/disskarsten.pdf) by Karsten Weicker (2003).